# Save .gif IndexError using .save() method with matplotlib.animation.ArtistAnimation()

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, gif, index-error

I've created a series of 3D images using `plt.plot_surface()` with `plt.scatter()` like the following:
[image]

And I'd like to save them as a .gif. Following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51512141/how-to-make-matplotlib-saved-gif-looping) I was able to loop through viewing angles and collect the images:

```
v_angles = [item for item in range(184,264,2)] + [item for item in range(264,183,-2)]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.animation import PillowWriter

ims = []
for angle in v_angles:
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (13,8))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, 
                    cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, 
                    alpha=0.67, 
                    edgecolor='white', 
                    linewidth=0.25, 
                    zorder=-1)
    im = plt.gcf()
    ims.append([im])
```

saving them as a `matplotlib.animation.ArtistAnimation()` object:

```
ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, 
                                ims,
                                interval=50,
                                blit=True,
                                repeat_delay=500)
```

It looks like the images (`ims`) were indeed collected and `ani` saved correctly:

```
In[574]: ims
Out[575]: 
[[<Figure size 936x576 with 1 Axes>],
 [<Figure size 936x576 with 1 Axes>],
 [<Figure size 936x576 with 1 Axes>],
...

In[576]: ani
Out[577]: <matplotlib.animation.ArtistAnimation at 0x107571fa90>
```

Yet when I try to create the .gif

```
writer = PillowWriter(fps=20)
ani.save("3d_scatter.gif", writer='imagemagick')
```

I get the following `IndexError`:

```
  File ".../anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 575, in finish
    self._frames[0].save(

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Looks like `self._frames` should contain items but does not.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You made a small mistake in the first part of your code. It should be like this:

```
for angle in v_angles:
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (13,8))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    im = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z,  #        <== NOTE THE CHANGE, I PREFIXED 'im = '.
                    cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, 
                    alpha=0.67, 
                    edgecolor='white', 
                    linewidth=0.25, 
                    zorder=-1)
    # im = plt.gcf()                        <== THIS LINE CAN BE REMOVED.
    ims.append([im])
```

Your post is almost a year old but I hope it still helps you or someone else.