# Generating figures in a loop and creating animation

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, while-loop

I'm doing a complicated calculation inside a while loop in Python, and plotting the results for each iteration in a figure. I'm having problems saving each figure and making a gif with these images. I tried the suggestions in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51512141/how-to-make-matplotlib-saved-gif-looping), but I don't know what to put in the `imshow` field:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np

thist = 4 # total time
tstep = 1 # time step

# ims is a list of lists, each row is a list of artists to draw in the
# current frame; here we are just animating one artist, the image, in
# each frame
ims = []

while thist>=tstep:

    x = np.linspace(0,2,100)
    y = np.sin(x*(thist-tstep)) # complicated calculation

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
    ax = plt.subplot(111)

    plt.plot(x,y)
    #plt.show()
    im = plt.imshow(fig)
    ims.append([im])

    tstep += 1

ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig,ims,interval=100,blit=True,repeat_delay=1000)
ani.save('mytest.gif', writer='imagemagick')
```

Comment: You should really just use `FuncAnimation`, not `ArtistAnimation`, which is more low level.  https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/animation_api.html  What you are doing is equivalent to https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/animation/animate_decay.html

Comment: do you really have to show image to save it ?