# Save several matplotlib plots as a looping gif?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

The following code of mine yields 38 plots of changing sea surface temperature data in a specific region. What would be the best way to stack them in order to create a looping gif, or some other method of turning it into a looping gif?

```
for yyyy in np.arange(1982, 2021):
    year = month_events.loc[(month_events['Year'] == yyyy)]
    meanhw = year.pivot_table(index='Lat', columns='Lon', values='#MHW days', aggfunc=np.mean).values
    X_unique = month_events.Lat.unique()
    Y_unique = month_events.Lon.unique()
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(Y_unique, X_unique)
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,16))
    ax1_j = fig.add_subplot(111)
    map1 = Basemap(llcrnrlon=289, llcrnrlat=39, urcrnrlon=297, urcrnrlat=45, projection='mill', resolution='h')
    a1 = map1.contourf(X, Y, meanhw, latlon=True, cmap='Reds')
    map1.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.5)
    map1.fillcontinents(color='lightgray')
    map1.drawstates(linewidth=0.5, color='gray')
    plt.colorbar(a1, ax=ax1_j, fraction=0.0429, pad=0.05, spacing='uniform', label='# days')
    plt.title('Year = %s' % yyyy, size=14, pad=14)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Best is entirely subjective.  I'm lazy and save the figures in .png format then convert to an animated gif with ImageMagick (https://askubuntu.com/questions/648244/how-do-i-create-an-animated-gif-from-still-images-preferably-with-the-command-l)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Matplotlib saved gif looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51512141/how-to-make-matplotlib-saved-gif-looping)

Answer (score 0):

After very frustrating attempts at directly converting a matplotlib figure to an image object, I gave up and fell back to the inefficient but easy method of saving the figure to an image file and reopening that image file:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

images = []
for yyyy in np.arange(1982, 2021):
    ...
    fig.savefig('tmp.png')
    images.append(Image.open('tmp.png'))
images[0].save('animated_plot.gif', save_all=True, append_images=images, duration=200, loop=0)
```

The `loop=0` argument means that the gif will loop indefinitely. If you only want it to loop a finite number of times, use that number instead of 0.

- [Documentation for PIL.Image.save](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save)